# Accessing elements inside a view - Backbone.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

---

EDIT : SOLVED

Two typos in the code, one as stated and another sneaky one,
Thanks alot and sorry for your time!

Hello SO,

My current issue occurred while exploring Backbone.js

I've created a simple HTML table using backbone, Each row is a model, The collection of all the rows is passed to a view that renders everything - so far, so good.

My table has the following classes : Each tablecell has a .tablecell class and each row has a .tablerow class.

I currently have a click event that fires correctly every time a table cell is clicked. 
What I'd like to figure out is how, if at all possible, can I access the 'clicked on' table cell and alter his attributes.
As a simple example, Change the class of a clicked cell or change the background color.

Can it even be done? Or am I missing something completely?

My current thought is that each cell must be a model of his own with his own view and his own event, but I doubt it should be so complicated.
Thanks in advance!

My single view is this :

```
            var rowView = Backbone.View.extend({

                //usual view attributes : el, model, initialize etc.

                events : 
                    {
                    "click.tablecell" : "clickOnCell",
                    },

                    clickOnCell : function(cell)
                    {
                        cell = $(cell.currentTarget);
                        cell.css("font-weight","bold");
                    },
                render : function () {

        // boring render method, renders correctly.

                },  
            });
```

Comment: You have a typo in your `events` (there should be a space between the event name and the selector) but the structure works otherwise: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/vYntw/ Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment;

A few things are a bit strange,
1)My event won't even fire with the space as you suggested
2)The event fires correctly as I want if i change the selector to "td" instead of the class name.
3)in your JSfiddle example there are no classes on the TD's, should that matter?

I'm still wondering why it doesn't fire for me or why i need the TD selector

Comment: I added the class to the `<td>`s in JavaScript because I was too lazy to put them in the template. Update the fiddle to match your situation, there's something going on in the code we can't see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add the event and handler to the `events` hash (you are missing a blankspace on your example):

```
events: { 'click .tablecell': 'clickOnCell' }
```

You receive the jQuery (or another framework you are replacing jQuery with) event object:

```
clickOnCell: function (e) {

    var $td = $(e.currentTarget);

    $td.css('color', 'red');

}
```

Understand that *event delegation* occurs at the end of view *instantiation*. By that, I mean that your view must have a the `el` property as your row.

If you cannot set `el` property during the view definition (which seems to be the case), try using `setElement` to your table row element during the `render`.

```
render: function () { 

   //...

   var myRow = $('<tr/>');

   this.setElement(myRow);        

   //...

}
```

Hope I've helped.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
While I did notice i have a typo, The reason i wrote it like that in the first place is because the event doesn't fire when written 'correctly'.

The event fires without a problem if i use 'click' or if i use 'click td', but if i try to use the class it won't fire, hence the typo.

In anycase, I'd love to hear any ideas you might have as to why a certain 'click .classname' doesn't work, or if you heard anything about it. google is dry for me

Comment: Event delegation occurs at the end of view instantiation. Have you set any "el" property to your table? By that, I mean: what `el` value do you get when you do view.el? It must be your table.

If you cannot set "el", try using `setElement` to your table element.

Comment: Main issue was the typo + another typo, I updated my original question, 
I thank you for your time and you did indeed teach me something new! 
Thanks again for your time.